# Cakephp form input field costum title throws error:

Tags: php, cakephp

This is rather simple but according to the documentation i can do the following:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('name', 'Produkt');
```

Where  `'Produkt` will be the title of the input field.

However when i try this i get the following error:

```
Warning (2): array_merge(): Argument #3 is not an array [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 1078]

Notice (8): Unenter code heredefined index: before [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 992]

Notice (8): Undefined index: between [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 992]

Notice (8): Undefined index: after [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 992]

Notice (8): Undefined index: format [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper.php, line 1200]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Note i have also tried the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('antal', array('title'=>'På lager'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $options = array()

The [method signature](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L959) for `input` is:

```
public function input($fieldName, $options = array()) {
```

Passing a string where the method expects an array will not work. If there is some documentation which suggests this should work - please point it out and/or submit a patch correcting it.

To set the title of an input, simply specify that as part of the options:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'Produkt'));
```

Regarding this additional point:

> Note i have also tried the following ...

Passing an array as the second parameter [cannot result in an array merge error](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1074), since the relevant variable will be an array. If there's a *different* error message, please point out what that is.

Comment: This removes the erros but doesnt change the title from name to Produkt.

Comment: That's because `title` isn't the right array key to use - see the docs or the doc block =)